# UIViews are subviews of UIScrollView. How to trace that a subview is inside defined rectangle?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I add UIViews to UIScrollView one under another. When user scrolls and current UIView passes a rectangle it has to change background color of UIView.
How to trace that a subview is inside defined rectangle?

```
- (void) showViews {

    CGRect scrollRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 44.0f, 704.0f, 704.0f); 

    UIScrollView *aScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollRect];
    float yPos = 20.0f;
    //the rectangle to trace intersection
    CGRect intersectRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 200.0f, 704.0f, 400.0f);

    for (UIView* view in arrayOfViews) {
        CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(100.0f, yPos, 320.0f, 480.0f); 
        view.frame = viewRect;
        [aScroll addSubView:view];
        yPos = yPos + 340.0f;
        aScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(704.0, yPos);
     }


}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: @PengOne Sorry, the question is in title. How to trace that a subview inside defined rectangle?

Comment: do you need to change the color when scroll stops or while scrolling ?

Comment: @Vince I need to change it while scrolling. When inside intersectRect color is blue, when outside color is green. Just to simplify.

Answer (score 1):

The does `CGRectIntersection();` might be what you are [looking](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html) for.

It returns a `CGRect`, the intersection, which can be null (check it with `CGRectIsNull()`). If the rects have same size, and they are one over the second, the result should be a `CGRect`with same size.

Comment: I know the function, but I don't understand what frames to compare, because views positioned relatively to UIScrollView.

Comment: Yes I made this answer after reading your comment @PengOne, isn't the scroll view delegate able to handle this ?

Comment: I just looked at delegate methods and I can't find a right one. Simple task but no idea yet:)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution in delegate method and property contentOffset.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    for (UIView *view in [[scrollView subviews] copy]) {

        if ((view.frame.origin.y - scrollView.contentOffset.y - self.controllStrip.frame.origin.y - self.controllStrip.frame.size.height) < 0  & 

             ( view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y - self.controllStrip.frame.origin.y) > 0) {

        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        }

        else 
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    }

}
```